# Boolean algebra implementation question

Tags: boolean-algebra

We could use boolean algebra to analyse the digital circuit and use boolean simplification to optimise the circuit.

In boolean expression "1 + A" is 1, whatever A is 1 or 0.

But in the real digital world, the result would be 0 if expression is "1+1" and  result is 1 bit. Does it mean we can't use the boolean algebra in any electronic case or I misunderstand something?

Comment: It's "boole**a**n", like you've used it once in your question, not "boolen" like you used thrice :) No big deal, I fixed that for you. You're wrong however. You're confusing the "OR" with the "XOR" operation, and these are two different things. What "+" means depends on context, but if nothing else is said, I'd assume "OR"

Comment: As others have pointed out, boolean algebra chooses to define the meaning of the symbol \$+\$ to indicate "inclusive OR." (There are good reasons for the choice.) That algebra also chooses to define the meaning of the symbol \$\oplus\$ to indicate "exclusive OR." You need to avoid conflating the two into a mush. They mean different things. So you need to keep your head straight when reading forward. If someone writes "OR" without either "inclusive or exclusive" then you should probably assume a priority for \$+\$ ("inclusive OR"), unless the context makes it otherwise clear to be \$\oplus\$.

Answer (score 1):

[The + symbol is "OR" rather than "sum" when discussing boolean algebra.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols)

The problem you are having is that you are confusing the usual meaning of + in mathematics with the boolean operator + for OR.

The function you describe is the boolean logic XOR (exlusive OR.)

This is also known as a half adder.  1 XOR 1 gives 0.